# Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'. in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, cross-platform

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find lifecycle-common-java8-2.2.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.2.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/lifecycle/lifecycle-common-java8/2.2.0/lifecycle-common-java8-2.2.0.jar
> Could not find lifecycle-common-2.2.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.2.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/lifecycle/lifecycle-common/2.2.0/lifecycle-common-2.2.0.jar
> Could not find core-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/arch/core/core-common/2.1.0/core-common-2.1.0.jar
> Could not find collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/collection/collection/1.1.0/collection-1.1.0.jar
> Could not find annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/annotation/annotation/1.1.0/annotation-1.1.0.jar

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

  Searched in the following locations:
  https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/annotation/annotation/1.1.0/annotation-1.1.0.jar
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             25.2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             25.2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Are you sure you're connected to the internet, check your firewall or may be you are using a VPN